# “ERROR TypeError: Object(…) is not a function” using AngularFirestore and firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic

Quiero utilizar Firebase y angularfire2 en mi app, lo primero que hice fue instalarlo con:

```
npm install firebase@latest angularfire2@latest --save
```

Después agregué las declaraciones:

En ***environment.ts***

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
firebase: {
apiKey: 'sfsdfdsff',
authDomain: 'sfsdfdf',
databaseURL: 'https://ng-sfsdfsf.firebaseio.com',
projectId: 'ng-fitnesssfsdfdsf',
storageBucket: 'ng-fsdfsdfsfdecff5.appspot.com',
messagingSenderId: '21331323'
}
```

En ***app.module.ts***, los imports:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFirestoreModule
```

En el component donde quiero obtener mi data:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

Hasta este momento no tengo ningun error, pero cuando trato de declarar la variable en el constructor para utilizarla:

```
constructor(private trainingService: TrainingService, private 
db:AngularFirestore) { }
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at eval (firestore.js:28)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
```

En mi ***package.json***:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.8.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^5.0.2",
```

Y no se porqué.

¿Alguien podria ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

recién tuve el mismo problema, y lo solucioné agregando

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Lo encontré en

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1668

Espero aún te pueda ayudar!

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza las siguientes librerías en tu archivo **package.json** :

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
"rxjs": "^6.1.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0"
```